# Compress all files in a folder with 7-zip using batch file

Tags: batch, 7-zip

I want to schedule a background task that will compress all files in a certain folder using 7-zip. I'd like to accomplish this using a batch file with the following settings:

[image]

Comment: What is the whole path of your Folder to zip ? I mean is like this one : `%userprofile%\Desktop\Test_Doc` ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].